# Read All Registrations azure notification hub python

Tags: azure, push-notification

am trying to retrieve a list of all devices registered in azure notification but i keep getting the same error 
[
  "`401`MissingAudience: The provided token does not specify the 'Audience'..TrackingId:38d0f9f4-9836-498",
  "2-a1d9-60f5ceed7210_G7,TimeStamp:1/28/2019 3:59:33 PM"
]

```
domain = "https://mnamespace1.servicebus.windows.net"
    url = domain + "/notificationhub/registrations/?api-version=2017-11"
    r = requests.get(url, headers = {
        # "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8",
        "authorization": 'WRAP access_token ="QeXuRZO2ATZM8jolXFYPDvQb4zWSzifmWvpS8eb5FLM="',
        "x-ms-version": "2017-11"})
    print (Response(r))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error information and code, the issue was caused by generating the sas token incorrectly.

Based on the description of REST API [`Read All Registrations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/dn223270(v%3Dazure.100)#response-codes), the correct sas token for this api should be like below, please refer to the section [`Create SAS Security Token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/dn495627(v%3Dazure.100)) to know how to generate.

```
SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3A%2F%2F<your servicebus name>.servicebus.windows.net%2F<your notification hub name>&sig=<signature with urlencode>&se=<expires>&skn=<police name, such as DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature>
```

The SAS token above is the same as for EventHub, so you can refer to the sample code in Python for EventHub to generate it, please refer to [`Generate SAS token` for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token#python) to write for Notification Hub.

Here is my sample code.

```
import time
from urllib import parse
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

def generate_sas_token(uri, sas_name, sas_value):
    target_uri = parse.quote_plus(uri)
    sas = sas_value.encode('utf-8')
    expiry = str(int(time.time() + 10000))
    string_to_sign = (target_uri + '\n' + expiry).encode('utf-8')
    signed_hmac_sha256 = hmac.HMAC(sas, string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256)
    signature = parse.quote(base64.b64encode(signed_hmac_sha256.digest()))
    return 'SharedAccessSignature sr={}&sig={}&se={}&skn={}' \
                     .format(target_uri, signature, expiry, sas_name)

api_version = '2017-11'
uri = 'https://<your servicebus name>.servicebus.windows.net/<your notificationhub name>/registrations/?api-version={}'.format(api_version)
sas_name = '<SharedAccessKeyName>' # for example, DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature
sas_value = '<SharedAccessKey>'
sas_token = generate_sas_token(uri, sas_name, sas_token)
```

Then, you can get the response of the REST API as the code below.

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Authorization':sas_token,
    'x-ms-version':api_version
}
r = requests.get(uri, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```